# Lua 5.2 - utf8 lower function - is there a pure lua implementation?

Tags: lua

I can't find any good implementation of `string.lower` for utf8 characters in pure Lua. Either it's a C++ library, which I can't use, because I have no access to the C-part in the project, or so called 'implementation' where `utf8.lower` just defaults to the `string.lower`. Obviously it doesn't work.

Is there a solution? Maybe someone can give a hint on how to implement this thing?

Comment: For limited set of languages (e.g, for your native language) you can write `utf8.lower` yourself.

Comment: The main problem is that I'm developing an extension which should work for multiple languages.

Comment: First customer in each country should send you a table of small-capital letters in his alphabet :-)

Answer (score 2):

Performing case conversion in Unicode (regardless of encoding) is *not* a simple exercise. Implementing Unicode case conversion requires access to Unicode characters property tables, and the algorithm itself is not merely "if character is uppercase, replace with lowercase version" because many languages don't have a 1:1 case conversion mapping for all characters.

That's not to say that it can't be done. But there's a reason why most people who need serious Unicode work default to using ICU or other libraries rather than coding their own.

Comment: What is ICU, if you could please supply a reference?